# Maximum of derivative hierarchy

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given a function $a(x)$, is

$\displaystyle\max\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{da(x)}{dx}\right) > \max\left(\frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^2a(x)}{dx^2}\right) > \max\left( \frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a(x)}{dx^3}\right) > \cdots $ always true?

If not, how can we argue about the convergence of taylor series or radius of convergence around the point zero if suddenly for example $\dfrac{d^3a(x)}{dx^3}$ is very large at one point?

Comment: If the question is about convergence of a power series centered at $0$, then the question of whether this holds at value of $x$ besides $0$ shouldn't matter. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy Should $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{da(x)}{dx} > \frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^2a(x)}{dx^2}> \frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a(x)}{dx^3} > \cdots $ be true at 0 if the power series need to converge centered at 0?

Comment: the Taylor series converges to the function iff the function is locally analytic. there are many non analytic $C^\infty$ functions. From the example of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function you can also show that some functions can fake to be analytic, with their Taylor series converging but not to the function. A sufficient condition for the Taylor series to converge to the function is that it is complex differentiable (= holomorphic : that's why complex analysis is so powerful)